# ASP.NET MVC date format

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code: `<%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.startDate)) %>`

It outputs something like 01/01/2011 00:00 but I would to ONLY show the date and not the time! How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:d}", item.startDate)) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= item.startDate.ToShortDate() %>
```

The above will take into account the current Locale and format it as the locale dictates.  There is also no point in using `Html.Encode()` since it's impossible for the output of the date function to contain anything dangerous that needs encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")) %>
```